# DAX Formula Issue - Detail level correct, but subtotals and totals not

Tags: dax, subtotal

I'm very new to DAX and strugglingly to understand how to correctly get subtotals for my formula.  My formula correctly calculates at the detail level, but I want it to sum the detail rows for the subtotals and totals rather than calculate the entire data set.

[Run Rate Subtotal Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWTBi.png)

The following is my forumla and attached is a sample file with my example.

RunRate:=(sum([Amount])/DISTINCTCOUNT([YearMonth]))*12-((max([FYPeriod])-distinctcount([YearMonth])))

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After further research (source: https://theexcelclub.com/learn-how-to-fix-totals-and-subtotals-in-dax-powerbi-and-power-pivot/), was able to solve my issue by creating 2 measures:

First to calculate the run rate if there was at least one value for the Key (lowest level of grouping for my data):

```
RunRate:=if(HASONEVALUE(BudgetKey[Key]),(sum([Amount])/DISTINCTCOUNT([YearMonth]))*12-((max([FYPeriod])-distinctcount([YearMonth]))))
```

Next, created a measure that summarized the first one and group by the various levels in my report:

```
NewRunRate:=If(HASONEVALUE(BudgetKey[Key])=true(),[RunRate],sumx(summarize(BudgetKey,BudgetKey[Key],BudgetKey[Description],BudgetKey[Category],BudgetKey[Dept]),[RunRate]))
```

[image: Final Product]